# ¿Por qué obtengo este error al crear una lista con un bucle while?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Estoy haciendo un pequeño código con listas el cual al momento de ejecutar me arroja el error

> IndexError: list index out of range en la linea 14

El código es el siguiente:

```
from random import randint

def imprimir(lista):
    i=0
    while i<len():
        print(lista[i])
        i+=1

lista=[]
n=int(input("ingrese la cantidad de elementos de la lista: "))
i=0
while i<n:
    valor=randint(0,9)
    lista[i].append(valor)
    i+=1

imprimir(lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

### ¿Por qué obtengo el error?

Veamos que implica esta expresión

```
lista[i].append(valor)
```

Se hace uso del método [`append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), este según su referencia:

> *list.**append(**x**)**:*
> Add an item to the end of the list. Equivalent to a[len(a):] = [x].

Según el prototipo, los objetos que cuentan con este método son **listas**. En la expresión en cuestión se está añadiendo a un indice específico de `lista`. Se espera que este elemento sea una lista y no lo es.

Esto ya es un error, pero no es el causante del

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Esto pasa ya que lista al haberse definido así `lista = []`, tiene cero elementos. En la iteración la expresión se interpretaría así

```
lista[0].append(valor)
lista[1].append(valor)
lista[2].append(valor)
...
```

Esto va a terminar en un error, debido a que claramente `lista` no tiene elementos. Por lo tanto ninguno de estos indices existe en la lista.

### ¿Cómo soluciono el error?

Según la referencia del método `append()` en [la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) (mencionada anteriormente). El método se debe de aplicar a listas. Por lo tanto solo basta con

```
lista.append(valor)
```

Esto añadirá al final el valor que se use como argumento del método. Sin embargo esto va a terminar en otro error:

```
TypeError: len() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

Esto se produce debido a que en el bucle `while` de la función `imprimir()`, se usa como condición

```
i < len()
```

`len()` por si solo no retorna un valor, y como dice en el error:

> Ocupa un argumento, se le dieron 0

Esto se soluciona cambiando la condición del bucle `while` a

```
i < len(lista)
```

Espero haberte ayudado.